# Can iOS devices continue emit as an iBeacon device when locked up?

Tags: ios, ibeacon

As you know iOS devices can be used as iBeacon devices. My question is, when using an iOS device as iBeacon, if you lock the screen without closing application that turns your device into iBeacon, will it continue to emit BLE ID to other devices?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no.  As soon as the lock screen comes up your application is no longer in the foreground, and transmission of the iBeacon advertisement will stop.

While you can advertise Bluetooth LE services in the background, this uses a special iOS format that is not compatible with the iBeacon profile.

Comment: Can other devices see something(ID or etc) while continueing to advertise in the background?

Comment: Other devices can see an iOS background bluetooth advertisement, yes.  But it won't be recognized as an iBeacon advertisement and won't trigger standard iOS iBeacon apps that use CoreLocation or Android Apps that use the Android iBeacon Library.  The receiving apps would have to have custom Bluetooth LE scanning code that looks for these iOS background advertisements.

Comment: One option might be to use a non-iOS based iBeacon such as [Estimote](http://estimote.com), [Roximity](http://roximity.com/), [Raspberry piBeacon](http://learn.adafruit.com/pibeacon-ibeacon-with-a-raspberry-pi/overview), or otherwise.